# Java how to enlarge a matrix

Tags: java, android, matrix-transform

In Android, I have:

1)  matrix (size is `257x257`, `float[257][257]`, each element represents a parameter to the image pixel);
2) image(size is `nx257`, `nx257`, `bytearray[n*257][n*257]`n is `float`, >=1)

How can I scale matrix to image size,repeat element and like below:
e.g.:

```
origin matrix:
1 2  
3 4
```

scale double to:

```
Target matrix:
1 1 2 2
1 1 2 2
3 3 4 4
3 3 4 4
```

If n*257 is not an integer, the edge is allowed to be inaccurate.
I know Python numpy how to do it,but in java/android,I haven't found a way to be efficient. Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: you have to manually create a new matrix with multiplied size, and then iterate through it filling it.

Comment: If you haven't found an efficient way then what have you found? Would be interesting to know so we don't suggest something you consider inefficient.